# Вопрос по синтаксису и пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Есть два предложения:

1) Во времена Шекспира обычай запрещал женщинам играть в театре.

2) Умение ориентироваться по слуху подсказывает китам, куда плыть.

Чем различаются концовки этих предложений с точки зрения синтаксиса? Почему в одном предложении есть запятая, а в другом – нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во втором предложении имеется придаточное предложение, присоединенное с помощью союза. Такие предложения выделяются запятыми.

В первом предложении придаточного предложения нет, а есть дополнение. Дополнения запятыми не выделяются.

Comment: Небольшое уточнение: ...соединенное с главным предложением с помощью союзного слова КУДА. А придаточные присоединительные предложения - это особый вид придаточных. Что касается дополнений, то  они могут, к примеру,  обособляться, если имеют уточняющее значение: обычай запрещал женщинам многое, и в частности играть в театре.

Answer (score 0):

Первое предложение простое.

Второе предложение сложноподчиненное, запятая отделяет придаточное предложение с
**союзным словом** *куда* от главного предложения.

Comment: инфинитив "играть" относится к "женщинам", а глагол "запрещал" —  это простое глагольное сказуемое.

Comment: Ваш уверенный тон не оставляет места для возражений. Ну-ну.

Comment: В книге Генриетты Граник "Секреты пунктуации", в разделе про сказуемые утверждается, что этот глагол (запрещал) — простое глагольное сказуемое.

Comment: На какой странице?

Comment: страница 54....

Comment: Да, нашел, и должен признать: я ошибся. Исправляю ответ. Спасибо за замечание.